# How to store np.ndarray to file?

Tags: python-3.x, file, numpy-ndarray

I have a ndarray with the shape (15,11,5). How to save the array to 5 files that includes 11 columns and 15 rows?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ndarray(shape=(15,11,5), dtype=float, order='F')

for i in range(5):
    with open('file{i}.txt', 'wb') as f:
        np.savetxt(f, np.column_stack(a[:,:,i]), fmt='%1.10f')
```

Comment: `'file{i}.txt'` -> `f'file{i}.txt'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ndarray(shape=(11,15,11), dtype=float, order='F')

k = 0
for j in a:
    k+=1
    with open(f'file{k}.txt', 'wb') as f:
        np.savetxt(f, j, fmt='%1.10f', delimiter=',')
```

Try this ^

Comment: Thank you and how to get 11 colums? The output is one long row.

Comment: I think it gives you 11 columns. Once check again?

Comment: Nope, it didnt, my bad. I edited the complete code again in the answer. Try running that. Also it saves from 1 now, So delete file0 and avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you, but now it creates 15 files instead of rows and 11 rows instead of 15.

Comment: So this creates 15 rows, 11 columns, and 11 files. So sorry for the late response but I suddenly got busy :/